# How to manage global variables and functions in vue3, typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, global-variables, vuejs3

I've just entered the vue and everything is confusing. I'm here for advice.

There is data that should be used for global and also I want to provide various functions that process this data.
At first, it was approached with a global variable declaration. But because of functions, I created a class that combines data and functions, and declared them as static. Data was initialized in the class's constructor.(with Axios get)
In addition, the object was declared in setup() of App.vue to use like a singletone.

<Common.ts>

```ts
export class DataManager {
  static datas: DataInfo[];
  constructor() {
    axios.get("api").then((res) => {
      for(const eachData of res.data) {
        DataManager.datas.push({
          id: eachData.id,
          name: eachData.name,
        })
      }
    ).catch(error -> {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  static getDataName(id: number) : string {
    const foundInfo = DataManager.datas.find((element : DataInfo) => {
      return element.id === id;
    })
    if(foundInfo === undefined) {
      return ""
    }
    return foundInfo.name;
  }
}
```

<App.vue>

```html
  setup() {
    const SingletonDataManager = new DataManager();
    return {
      SingletonDataManager
    }
  }
```

Is this the best way? or is there any better way for global variables and functions?
If singleton is a right way, I think that without static just sharing the singleton object by provide/Inject is better... right?
Please give me some advice.

**UPDATE using composible**

```js
const datas = ref([] as DataInfo[])

axios.get("api").then((res) => {
  for(const eachData of res.data) {
    Object.assign(datas.value, eachData)
  }
).catch(error -> {
  console.log(error)
}

export function useDataManager() {
  const getDataName = (id: number) => {
    return blahblah
  }

  return {
    datas,
    getDataName,
  }
}
```

Comment: A class isn't reactive, unless it's wrapped with `reactive`, unless an instance is wrapped with `reactive`, but then DataManager.datas will stay non-reactive because it refers to original class. You're reinventing the wheel. This is what global stores are for. Pinia, for starters

Comment: @EstusFlask I didn't think about reactive. Pinia. Thank you. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's a perfect candidate for [composable](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html)

Here is a basic example:

```html
<script setup>
// DataName.vue
import { UseDataManager } from './DataManager'

const dataManager = UseDataManager()
</script>

<template>{{ dataManager.getDataName() }}</template>
```

```js
// DataManager.ts

const dataManager = new DataManager();
export function UseDataManager(){
  return dataManager;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about Composable. Well, even if the DataManager declared globally is wrapped in composable, the reactivity is unlikely to be resolved. So instead of declaring DataManager as a class, I tried to declare datas global and provide them with functions wrapped in composable. In this way, I think I can catch both the initial purpose of providing variables and functions and reactivity. I guess it's right?

Comment: I just posted updated code above